# substance vs material

Tags: word-difference

Please help me to understand the difference between *Material* and *Substance*.

For instance please tell me what would differ if I change the *substance* word in the text below with *Material*.

> **Wikipedia :**  An oven is a thermally insulated chamber used for the heating, baking
>   or drying of a *substance*. It is most commonly used for cooking.

Comment: To me, if you replace *substance* with *material*, if will sound as if you were going to build something. But that's just me. BTW, I think *substance* and *material* can be used almost interchangeably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is probably best answered by a chemist or a scientist, but I have tried to do a summary. I found it to be a very interesting and intriguing question, and as @Damkerng said in the comments: "substance and material can be used almost interchangeably"

### Substance

In general, *substance* can refer to anything that is a nutrient and can be ingested, e.g., food, medicine, drugs etc. and it describes liquid and chemical forms. It is also a component of a material, or a finished product; basically anything which is made of matter.

In science the four states of matter; [solid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid), [liquid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid), [gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas), and [plasma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_%28physics%29) are either substances themselves or composed of different substances.

> **Solid**
>   While many common objects, such as an ice cube or a coin, are
>   chemically identical throughout, many other **common materials** comprise
>   a number of **different substances** packed together.
>
> **Liquid**
>   Pure *substances* that are liquid under normal conditions include water,
>   ethanol and many other organic solvents.
>
> **Gas**
>   Since gas molecules can move freely within a container, their mass is normally characterized by density. Density is the amount
>   of mass per unit volume of a *substance*, or the inverse of specific
>   volume.
>
> **Plasma**
>   As the voltage increases, the current stresses **the material** (by electric polarization) beyond its dielectric limit
>   (termed strength) into a stage of electrical breakdown, marked by an
>   electric spark, where the material transforms from being an insulator
>   into a conductor (as it becomes increasingly ionized).

### Material

Material, on the other hand, is often a finished product which is not normally ingested, absorbed or injected. Steel, iron, wood, plastic and paper are all different types of materials used to build or make a finished product. *Material* usually means; *matter*, *fabric*, *substance*, or *cloth*.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material#Raw_materials_and_processing) says:

> Material is anything made of matter, constituted of one or more
>   substances. Wood, cement, air, water and any other matter are all
>   examples of materials. Sometimes the term "material" is used more
>   narrowly to refer to substances or components with certain physical
>   properties that are used as inputs to production or manufacturing. In
>   this sense, materials are the parts required to make something else,
>   from buildings and art to airplanes and computers. [...]
>
> ### Some examples of raw materials
>
> **Cotton**
>
> An example of a raw material is cotton, which is harvested from
>   plants. Cotton can be processed into rope (also considered a raw
>   material), which can then be woven into cloth, a semi-finished
>   material. Cutting and sewing the fabric turns it into a garment, which
>   is a finished product.

Comment: I do not see any implication of nutrient or edible in the word substance. It might be a flammable substance it might be a resilient substance, etc.

Comment: Look at: "a particular kind or species of matter with uniform properties" and click on "show 120 types..." here: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/substance

Comment: @GeorgeWhite  The subject is vast, and I've only attempted a summary. But I realize that people will find omissions, faults and inaccuracies in my answer.

Comment: I like your answer (s a physician and former molecular biologist, I very much agree with you.) [This](http://www.yourdictionary.com/substance) source supports what you have stated.

Comment: @Susan thank you! I was hesitant before posting, I didn't want to appear foolish or naive.  :)